# Multiple DataAnnotation doesn't work

Tags: c#, data-annotations

I have this code in my class:

```
[Required(
    ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof (Resources),
    ErrorMessageResourceName = "VALIDATION_ERROR_ISO"
    )]
[StringLength(3,
    ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof (Resources),
    ErrorMessageResourceName = "VALIDATION_ERROR_STRING_LENGTH_3"
    )]

public virtual string ISO
{
    get { return iso; }
    set
    {
        iso = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("ISO");
    }
}
```

and this method to validate:

```
public bool IsValid
{
    get
    {
        var validationContext = new ValidationContext(this, null, null);
        return Validator.TryValidateObject(this, validationContext, validationResults);
    }
}
```

In my unit-test:

```
var testLanguage = new Language(){ISO = "More than 3 characters"};
Assert.IsTrue(!testLanguage.IsValid);
```

It is valid. If the ISO property is null, it isn't valid because of the required attribute. It seems that my IsValid doesn't check the Stringlength(3) attribute?

I use Visual Studio 2010

Thank you in advance

Edit:

I have found my mistake:

```
return Validator.TryValidateObject(this, validationContext, validationResults);
```

needs the true-flag to check all properties. Now it works with:

```
return Validator.TryValidateObject(this, validationContext, validationResults, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Put it upside down and it will work. Try this

```
[StringLength(3,
    ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof (Resources),
    ErrorMessageResourceName = "VALIDATION_ERROR_STRING_LENGTH_3"
    )]
[Required(
    ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof (Resources),
    ErrorMessageResourceName = "VALIDATION_ERROR_ISO"
    )]
public virtual string ISO
{
    get { return iso; }
    set
    {
        iso = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("ISO");
    }
}
```

Comment: Create a sample MVC application and bind ISO with a textbox and my code will work. I have tested on my environment. If I put Required before StringLength then StringLength validation does not fire but opposite is working.